# opening sdcard gallery album directory

Tags: android

Hi I am making the button which opens gallery(Default)album in sd card
putting following funtion to the button 
But i don't understand why this funtion makes whole application stops...

```
public void goTopAlbum(View v){
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Let's open gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent mIntent = new Intent(getIntent().ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image/Album1"));
         //dataType name = new dataType
         startActivity(mIntent);
     }
```

Comment: please post log

Answer (score 1):

```
  getIntent().ACTION_VIEW
```

Change to

```
  Intent.ACTION_VIEW
```

Comment: goTopAlbum(View) seems a click listener so getIntent() shouldn't be null here.